# Since yesterday I can't login to iOS developer forum. What's going on?

Tags: ios, developer-program

Since yesterday I can't login to the iOS developer forums, and I just subscribed 3 weeks ago. This is the error I get:

[image: Dev Forums error]

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the site was swamped, everyone trying to access at once, because of the announcements yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

Your ID needs someone to look into it. Reach out at http://developer.apple.com/contact and perhaps read through the steps [here](http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/purchase-and-next-steps.html#purchasecomplete).